# How to programmatically access information entered in the Admin panel?

Tags: theme, xml, php-5.4, magento-community, action

I’m new to Magento, and beginning to understand how it works, but I’m a bit unclear as to how to find the right “get...” and “set...” methods to access data (particularly from the Admin pages) and understanding how/where Magento is finding these methods.

For example, I want to put jQuery and other scripts in the HTML Head section.  My intuition is to put it in the “Miscellaneous Scripts” section of the System>>Config>>Web>>HTML Head section.

I check out head.phtml and find

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

which leads me to Head.php, where it looks like the method that’s getting the “Miscellaneous Scripts” is getCssJsHtml.

However, I’m not sure, and in general I’m wondering how to find what these methods do and how they related to the Magento files and Admin GUI?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts or style sheets should be added with layout updates. This can be done either within your theme or layout updates in admin panel like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>below_ie7.css</name></action>
</reference>
```

You can find more info in [this article](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2013/10/24/adding-javascript-and-css-files-to-head-section-of-magento.html).

Comment: Beautiful this helps a lot, thank you!  
However, this doesn't really answer my question as to how I would have found this information in Magento itself, i.e. how I go about finding which methods interface with the Admin panel, and in general how to find the right method for a certain situation...?

Comment: This all very specific. There's no general rule so you have to ask exactly what methods you want to found. For example the functionality described above resides in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head ` class.